# dynamic variable setting <href> into Ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax

Hi All i have a quick question about JSON data into href for AJAX

I have JSON coming into AJAX example data[i].listingid
How do i put that into a href inside the ajax?

Below are my codes, it will explain the situation more clearly.

Thanks for your time

```
<script>
$.ajax({
     type: "GET",
     url: "listing.php",

     dataType: 'json',
     success: function (data) {
         for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
             console.log(data)

             var listingid = data[i].listingid;
             var myOtherUrl =
                 "SpecificListing.html?Listingid=" + encodeURIComponent(listingid);


             var html1 = "<div class=two> Listing Address : " + data[i].address + "<a href=myOtherurl>" +
                 data[i].listingid + "Click to view the details" + "</div>" +
                 "</a>"
             $('#display12').append(html1);
         }
     }

 });
</script>
```

Comment: You also need to close your A before your DIV

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can straightly add it with concatenation like below :

```
var html1 = "<div class=two> Listing Address : " + data[i].address + 
  "<a  href='"+ myOtherurl +  "'>"+
   data[i].listingid+"Click to view the details" + "</a></div>";
```

or else you can use **jquery attr** method after you finish with appending html to div like below:

```
var listingid = data[i].listingid;
var myOtherUrl = "SpecificListing.html?Listingid=" + encodeURIComponent(listingid);

var html1 = "<div class=two> Listing Address : " + data[i].address + 
  "<a id='hrefholder'  >"+
    data[i].listingid+"Click to view the details" + "</a></div>";
$('#display12').append(html1); 

$('#hrefholder').attr("href",myOtherurl  );
```

**Tip :** Don't forget to add id to anchor tag

Answer (score 0):

Here's a cleaned up version of your callback (I try to avoid string concatenation for HTML as much as possible):

```
var successCallback = function(data) {
    var baseUrl = 'SpecificListing.html?Listingid=';

    for (var i=0; i<data.length; i++) {
        var listingId = data[i].listingid;
        var newUrl = baseUrl + encodeURIComponent(listingId);
        var $newDiv = $('<div />').addClass('two');
        var $newLink = $('<a />')
            .attr('href', newUrl)
            .text(listingId + ': Click to view details');

        $newDiv.append($newLink);
        $('#display12').append($newDiv);
    }
};
```

Find a full working implementation including simulated AJAX call here:

http://jsfiddle.net/klenwell/N2k8X/

Answer (score -1):

```
var html1 = "<div class=two> Listing Address : " + data[i].address + "<a href=myOtherurl>" + data[i].listingid+"Click to view the details" + "</a></div>";
```

Will work. Are u binding ajax event to this link?

Comment: But the dynamic data, data[i].listingid from the link isnt sticking to the link tho

Comment: What i am trying to do is the link to be for example  SpecificListing.html?Listingid=609; but at the moment the link is myOtherurl

Answer (score -1):

Anjith and Orion are both right but ya'll have a typo: 
the variable in your definition is called myOtherUrl but inside your concatenated string it is myOtherurl. Variables are case-sensitive. 
your variable will be parsed as a variable if you leave your double quotes around it so it's good as is

Comment: updated answer to correct type. However your this suggestion should go as comment . Instead of answer.